# Screenshot an element which is not visible?

Tags: java, swing, screenshot, paintcomponent

I'm trying to get a screenshot of a component in a JFrame. 
The problem is that this component is huge, and you can't see it entirely in the window (you have to scroll down to see the hidden part). 
I tried several things, for example this :

```
Rectangle rect = component.getBounds();

    try {
        String format = "png";
        String fileName = component.getName() + "." + format;
        BufferedImage captureImage =
                new BufferedImage(rect.width, rect.height,
                                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        component.paint(captureImage.getGraphics());

        ImageIO.write(captureImage, format, new File(fileName));

        System.out.printf("The screenshot of %s was saved!", component.getName());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
```

And this ([coming from here](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/)) :

```
BufferedImage bi;
    try {
        bi = ScreenImage.createImage( component  );
        ScreenImage.writeImage(bi, "Screen-Image.jpg");
    } catch (AWTException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But in both case, the screenshot I get only shows what I can see in the window. 
So if i scrolled down, i miss the part above, and if i scroll up i miss the bottom. 
Do you know how I could do to render the whole component in a picture ?

Comment: Your question is an xyz problem question where you're asking how to solve the wrong problem. You don't want to get a screen shot of non displayed items but rather an image rendering of a component.

Comment: Your first code-snippet looks fine for me. It will save the whole `component` regardless of how much of it is actually visible on screen.

Comment: Works fine for me using the `ScreenImage` class. I tried one test using a JTextArea with many lines of text and another with a panel containing a 1000 buttons in 5 columns. In both cases the components were added to a JScrollPane. Try doing the same and post your [mcve] if you have a problem.

Comment: Don't call `paint`, call `printAll`, but call it on the component inside the `JScrollPane`.  If you have a number components on a container which also includes one or more `JScrollPane`s you will need to create a offscreen version of the container which doesn't include the scroll panes (just puts the components directly on the container), size it and then capture the output